# Cordova useless to apps with more than 50 mb?

Tags: cordova

I've started to use Apache Cordova to port a Web Site to a mobile application. The objective was to reduce the development time once the Cordova builds iOS and Android apps with the same source code. But it seems it was wrong. In iOS we've developed the application and it was submitted to Apple Store without problems. But Apache Cordova seems to be useless to Google Store.

The application has 200Mb and there's no way to reduce its size. The paths are relative and the css uses url:'../../images.png'. This makes the use of some apkreader pack impossible.

Some one has a suggestion to split the application to upload it to Google Store? I'm starting to thing that Apache Cordova was a terrible error and we will have an enourms prejudice - maybe the only solution is develop everything again with Native apps.

I'm needing some help. I can't believe that Cordova hasn't an email to support directly his customers.

If your application will have more than 50 Mb you shouldn't use Cordova?

Thanks Fernando Campos Portugal - the project was to the Biggest portuguese air transporter.

Comment: The problem is google play doesn't accept apps bigger than 50MB, why is that phonegap's fault? If you develop a full native app bigger than 50MB you will have the same problem. Read the link Steve provided and use the expansion files.

Comment: Is not a Phonegap problem, that's right. But shouldn't be a Phonegap problem provide a plugin to solve this issue - a plugin implemented by phonegap? Android is what it is, and shouldn't be necessary to use a 3rd party plugin to solve the problem, once is a platform problem. That's just my opinion. I'm thinking that Phonegap couldn't develop a better solution to this issue.

Comment: why should phonegap take care of that? that's a google play problem, you can build big apps with phonegap but you can't distribute them on google play, so complain to google for having that stupid limitations. Phonegap team provides a common API, your problem only affects to distributing on google play, not even an android problem.

Answer (score 1):

Android allows APK Expansion Files for apps of more than 200MB. I wrote an article about this from a Cordova user standpoint. You can see if these steps are good for your app: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/adding-an-android-apk-expansion-file-to-a-cordova-project/

Comment: Last friday i've tried you articile to solve my problem. The article is very good, but just if we want to do an application that only works on Android. When we chose Cordova the objective was to develop once and have two applications: one for Android and one for iOS. Following this article I was able to learn that I need to have two branches, one to iOS and one to Android. This wasn't supposed to happen. To me cordova should work inside the obb extensions - it was the only way to garantee the main goal of Cordova - develop once and have two applications.

Comment: You found an exception to the rule :) iOS doesn't have this problem, so the article does not apply to iOS, only Android. So you would use the Merges folder to keep them together.